# Trying to create toolbar and getting rendering error

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create a toolbar but im getting error. I searched and didnt found solution. This is the error:
The following classes could not be found: android.support.v7.widget
my api version is 16.
This is my styles.xml file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Do you have the appcompat library included in your project?

Comment: @Tanis.7x I think I have, how I can check it?

Comment: Assuming your project uses gradle, check your app module's build.gradle for something like `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'`

Comment: @Tanis.7x I have newer version com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this error? Could you take a screenshot?

Comment: @Tanis.7x I cant now, but Im getting the error in activity_main.xml and Its show me instead the new tool bar i created i see on the phone inside the android studio gray square with text on it and the text is: android...widget and also i see same thing in the tool_bar.xml that contain the toolbar